# Build webapp to IOS app without xcode

Tags: ios, build

I dont know If someone did this so far I heard of a project which allows u to use the build scheme in windows but I cant find it so far.

Or is there any other idea how to do this.

(I don't want to store the app into applestore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of program or framework you're look for, but you can checkout this:

https://gigaom.com/2010/02/12/how-to-create-an-iphone-web-app/

http://snippetspace.com/portfolio/iwebkit/

It's a framework to build webapps.